# Hosting Node server on IP and Port

Tags: node.js, server, ip

I am having a project to make a GPS tracker app, I'm was planning to buy a cheap Chinese tracker,
The tracker can be set to forward data on an IP and a port like 192.168.0.1:8008 (just an example).

I can make a nodejs server but if I deploy it on heroku it gives me url instead of IP port, so where should I deploy it?

I want the server to be made so that I can make my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services which are listed as Virtual Machines (VM) typically provide you an option to have a static IP address attached to your server instance.

These are some of the popular providers (non-exhaustive list, not in any particular order):

- AWS (EC2)
- Azure (Virtual Machine)
- Google Cloud (Compute Engine)
- Digital Ocean (Droplet)